# Strange definition of K->G0 in k.h (C++ KDB)

Tags: c++, kdb

I have look at K definition and macro kF:

```
typedef struct k0{
  signed char m,a,t;
  C u;
  I r; 
  union {G g;H h;I i;J j;E e;F f;S s;struct k0*k;struct{J n;G G0[1];};};
  }*K;
#define kG(x)   ((x)->G0)
#define kF(x)   ((F*)kG(x))
```

According to the manual we can can access `kF(x)[42]` to get the 42nd element of the vector, but after using all macros the following code should be generated

```
F i = ((F*)(x->G0))[42]
```

But I think there is a problem with conversion of `G G0[1]` to `(F*) G0`, because we could get out of memory allocated to struct (`sizeof(G[1])==1` and `sizeof(F*)==8`).

I think the definition should be corrected from `G G0[1]` to `G* G0`. Where i am wrong?

Comment: The structure seems to be from before C got [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). Or as a (bad) workaround for having flexible array member in C++ (which doesn't have it).

Comment: On an unrelated note, if the code you show is actual copy-pastes code from the library or the source of KDB, then my suggestion is that you stay as far away from it as you possible can. Besides the issue with the (un)flexible array member, the names of the types, members, type-alias of pointers, and the use of macros, indicates very bad code.

Comment: Yes, this code is for C, but I try to use it in C++. And, yes, the code from their official header to their dynamically-loaded library. I have founded all answers in article about flexible array members, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are dealing with an object in kdb think of the K struct (actually k0 struct since K is really a pointer to a k0 struct) as the header of the list.  The G0 really marks the beginning of where the list starts if your K object is infact a list.  For instance a list of 16 floats might be allocated as follows.

```
K my_list = malloc(offsetof(struct k0, G0) +  sizeof(F) * 16);
my_list->t = KF;
my_list->n = 16;
```

See here how the k0 struct really just takes up the beginning of the memory and the extra space for the array is allocated after it starting at G0[0] with enough room to hold 16 floats.

Note that kdb does not actually use malloc since they have some sort of memory pool.  The above is just a simplified example of how it might work.